# Child component not subscribing to service observable

Tags: angular, angular5

Hey guys any inputs on what i have missed here? basically the parent component will trigger a click to open a modal through service using observable and the child component will subscribe to it, but it seems child method is not firing.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

ModalService

import { Injectable,TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

  private modalOpenedSource = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  modalOpened$ = this.modalOpenedSource.asObservable();

  public openModal(modal: any){
    this.modalOpenedSource.next(modal);
  }
}

Parent

 constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {
   this.loadItems();
 }
 openContractFormModal() {
   this.modalService.openModal('')
 }

Child

  public subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { 
    this.subscription = this.modalService.modalOpened$.subscribe(
      modal => {
        this.openModal();
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  openModal() {
    alert('works')
  }
```

Comment: Can you supply details around the child component usage in your parent's template? Also, where is the `ModalService` being provided?